# json nested array

Tags: .net, arrays, json

I've had a look at the existing answers on this, but it's not really helping me... :) I'm trying to access the file;

```
{   "user":{
    "name":"something",
    "sessionid":"local"   },   "stats-change":[
    {"1000":1},
    {"1004":1},
    {"2000":5997},
    {"1001":1},
    {"1100":821},
    {"2020":10},
    {"2010":3},
    {"2023":1},
    {"5242880":1},
    {"16777253":4}   ],   "checksum":"3f3c02b018c90c56793623c854ffbb64" }
```

I want to iterate through the stats-change elements, I've got;

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(_StatsFile);
```

which allows me to isolate stats-change, but I can't seem to case the dynamic back to a dictionary so I can use the keys, values of the stats change bit..

I'm sure this is simple, but it's eluding me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast the `stats-change` entry itself to a `Dictionary`, because it is not one.  It is an array.  You will have to treat it as an array, and then cast each element in that array to a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Is there any easy way to change it into a string array?